# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for Infinite (Non-negative) Series

Tags: analysis

I have been searching for a satisfactory proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for infinite (non-negative) series, but to no avail. The 'non-negative' qualifier is placed in parentheses because I am unsure as to whether it is a necessary condition for the inequality to hold; the only situation in which I've seen the inequality asked to be proven is in the case of non-negative series.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Are these series sums of real numbers? What inner product are you using?

Comment: Luenberger's optimization by vector space methods (section 2.10 p 29-30) covers this for the Holder Inequality in lp spaces (and Cauchy Schwarz is the special case where p = 2)